# i am unable to boot with my latest rpi-3.18.0 kernel and enabling the device tree?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, boot, device-tree

I am working on the latest rpi kernel ie 3.18.0 and by enabling the device tree.

I compiled the source code and with that image and modules i am unable to boot.

I am getting a blank screen and its not booting.

I added the following into the config.txt even though i am unable to boot

```
device_tree=bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
device_tree_address=0x100 
kernel_address=0x8000 
disable_commandline_tags=2
```

But with the image and modules that are given in the link https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/next , it is booting well with the same config.txt file

and i also using the firmware that are from the link https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/next

Comment: I downloaded the source code from https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.18.y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the rpi bootloader that your kernel has device tree enabled. You can do it using the `mkknlimg` tool from the `raspberrypi/tools` repository, e.g.:

```
mkknlimg linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage kernel.img
```

This will add a trailer to the kernel, thus marking it as "device tree compatible".